# Bash script to recursively find and replace in files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

1. I want to find all occurrences of this:

> ```
> [UIFont tly_primaryFontWithWeight:TVFontWeight300 size:14.0f]
> ```

2. Parse whatever is after "size:" and before the closing square bracket. In this case it would be "14.0f".
3. And then replace that occurence with this:

> ```
> [UIFont tly_primaryFontWithSize:14.0f];
> ```

How can I do so?

Comment: This is BashFAQ #21 ("How can I replace a string with another string in a variable, a stream, a file, or in all the files in a directory?"): http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021

Comment: Why do you need to parse the `14.0f`? You would likely be able to just match `tly_primaryFontWithWeight:TVFontWeight300 size:` and replace it with `tly_primaryFontWithSize:`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003706/how-can-i-recursively-replace-a-string-with-another-in-many-files-using-bash, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260802/recursively-traverse-directory-and-replace-function-calls and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307796/how-do-i-replace-php3-with-php-inside-every-file-in-a-directory are among those (many) duplicates.

Comment: BTW, the one thing that makes this at all different from the first three duplicates I find searching SO is that you want to use a backreference. That's easily done, if you use GNU sed with the `-r` option for ERE; it might look like `size:([^]]+)\]` on the match side, and then you'd use `\1` in the replace side to refer to the matched content... but that's if you ignore lurker's (good) advice; follow that advice and the duplicates are exactly relevant as-is.

Comment: @lurker didn't think of it that way, good advice!